# Choose author credentials for git repositories based on some subdirectory

Tags: git, bash

I work simultaneously for different employers. And I have to use different credentials in commits base on the employer. I could easily run `git config author.email` and `git config author.name` in each repository. But I'd like to do it globally as there are many repositories for each employer and new ones appear quite regularly.

I arrange all repositories in two folders. i.e. `~/projects/<employer_name1>/<project_name>` and `~/projects/<employer_name2>/<project_name>`.

So what I'd like to do is to make git automatically choose correct commit credentials based on the location of the current repository (which employer subdirectory it is).

Found the answer myself. Added this to .bashrc:

```sh
function git() {
  case $(readlink -f .)/ in 
    $(readlink -f /home/cryo/projects/fun-box)/*) GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=my_name GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=my@email.com /usr/bin/git $*;;
    *) /usr/bin/git $*;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: Found this script http://www.mikeivanov.com/different-emails--for-different-git-repositori

It selects author email. I would be happy if it could also select author name

Comment: Yes. I know that will work. Thank you. But it is not really what I am looking for as I will have to run the script with correct arguments for every new projects. And I am sure I will forget to do it sooner or later. So I am more into the solution I provided in the link above. I'd be happy to have it modified to choose not the email only, but author/email pair.

Answer (score 2):

Have a centralized mechanism for creating repos. Like some script in your path etc. whereby you do:

```
repo create -e employer -n name
```

or something like that.

The repo command ( just an example, nothing to do with the one from Android ) will create the repo for you in the necessary location and read a config file and set the credentials for that repo based on the employer etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user.name and user.email, among any other settings at the repo level. Just script it if you like.

Comment: Yeah. I am aware of that. But it is not what I am looking for. I have dozens of projects for each employer. The projects are quite small and new ones created about every week. So I believe I'll forget to set specific author name and email once if following this way. That is why I'd rather do some .bashrc alias to git to manage credentials for me automatically. But still thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have a finite set of emails, or do you potentially get a new one when a new project comes in?

Comment: Yes. I do have a finite set of author/email pairs. Each pair for a particular employer I work for.

Comment: What about adding a repo per employer and each project is spun off as a submodule of each employer. This way you automagically get the email and name "inherited" from the top level repo. Thoughts? I'll add this as another answer..

Answer (score 0):

Add a top level repo for each employer. Make each new project a submodule of this repo. This should allow you not to worry about the name and email settings for each project from now on.